# Creating multiple new vectors from original vector

Tags: r

I have a vector d and I create new vector from d such that new vector contain every mth element of d:

```
v<-d[seq(1,length(d),m)]
```

the next step I would like to calculate the sum

```
s<-sum(abs(v[1:(length(v)-1)]-v[2:length(v)]))
```

It would be no problem if I do this with few values of m. However, if I have a more than 50 values for m, doing this one by one will not be a desired way. I think of generalising the way of creating v corresponding with different value of m. The following is the code that I came up with:

```
d1<-rnorm(20)
m<-seq(1,10,1)
v<-matrix(rep(0,length(d1)*lenght(m)),nrow=length(m))
for (i in 1:length(m)){v[i,]<-d1[seq(1,length(d1),m[i])]}
```

but when I run the code, the following error appear:

```
Error in v[i, ] <- d1[seq(1, length(d1), m[i])] : 
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

So I tried another way:

```
v<-rep(0,length(d1))
for (i in 1:length(m)){v<-d1[seq(1,length(d1),m[i])]}
```

but this code only give me the value of v at m=m[length(m)], not all vectors v corresponding with m[1]to m[length(m)]. Could anyone suggest me a function/a way to solve this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It would help if you posted a (small and simplified!) example of the input data and desired output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are perhaps trying to do this:

```
for (i in 1:length(m)){assign(paste0("v",i), d1[ seq(1, length(d1), m[i])] }
```

My advice ... don't. You should be learning to build lists:

```
vres <- lapply( seq_along(m) , 
                  function(i) d1[ seq(1, length(d1), m[i])] )
```

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust, this works perfectly and I can do lots of things with `vres`. I really should learn how to build list because it works better than loop in many cases. Thanks again for giving me great suggestion that help improving my experience with R

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid `for` loops and use the `apply` family instead. Your function generates a bunch of vectors of different lengths, which I combine into a list. Both data frames and matrices have to be even, or non-ragged, so I have to pad your vectors with `NA`s, then I column bind them.

Does this work?

```
set.seed(2001)
d1 <- rnorm(20)
m <- seq(1, 10, 1)
ragged <- lapply(m, FUN=function(x) d1[seq(1, length(d1), x)]) 
maximum <- max(sapply(ragged, length))
even <- lapply(ragged, FUN=function(x) {
               xx <- rep(NA, maximum)
               xx[seq(length(x))] <- x
               xx
})
even1 <- do.call(cbind, even)
```

Comment: Thanks @RichardHerron, it perfectly creates matrix even1 with each column is new vector derived from d1. But when I try this to perform the following: `s<-apply(even1,2,sum)`, it will only return the sum of the first column, and returns NA for sum of the rest column because other columns contain NA. So I try to select all element that is not NA by: `s<-apply(even1,2,function(v) v[ !is.na(v) ] )` and apply `s<-apply(even1,2,sum)` again but I still get same result as before.

Comment: @Ocean you need to pass na.rm = TRUE as an option to sum(). You could also use sapply(ragged, sum).

Comment: `@Richard Herron`yes, silly me,it works now. Thanks for your help